# Is it possible to have an optional Key property in a DSC resource?

Tags: powershell, wmi, dsc

I'm creating a custom DSC resource and I wanted a certain property to be part of the key to the resource, but at the same time be optional:

- if the user does specify it in the configuration, it should be part of the key, so that one would not be able to create two instances with the same value.
- if the user does not set it, it should behave as if it was also be part of the key but with a null value, so that the user cannot instantiate more than one resource with all other keys the same, but without setting this optional parameter

Basically what I'd like is the following:

The schema.mof file

```
[ClassVersion("1.0.0.0"), FriendlyName("cMyResource")]
class Mobiltec_cMyResource : OMI_BaseResource
{
    [Key, Description("Name")] string Name;
    [Key, Description("Key1")] string Key1;
    [Key, Description("This is a key only if it is specified")] string OptionalKey2;
    [Write, Description("Ensures"), ValueMap{"Present","Absent"}, Values{"Present","Absent"}] string Ensure;
};
```

A simple representation of the implementation I want:

```
function Set-TargetResource
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$Key1,

        # Note that this is not mandatory
        [string]$OptionalKey2,

        [ValidateSet("Present","Absent")][string]$Ensure = "Present"
    )
...
}
```

And the usage:

Valid:

```
cMyResource Res1
{
    Name = 'name'
    Key1 = 'key1'
    OptionalKey2 = 'key2'
    OtherParameter = 'param'
}

cMyResource Res2
{
    Name = 'name'
    Key1 = 'key1'
    OptionalKey2 = 'otherKey2'
    OtherParameter = 'param'
}
```

Also valid:

```
cMyResource Res1
{
    Name = 'name'
    Key1 = 'key1'
    OtherParameter = 'param'
}

cMyResource Res2
{
    Name = 'name'
    Key1 = 'otherKey1'
    OtherParameter = 'param'
}

cMyResource Res3
{
    Name = 'name'
    Key1 = 'otherKey1'
    OptionalKey2 = 'key2'
    OtherParameter = 'param'
}
```

When I declare the property as key though, whenever I try to use the resource in a configuration without specifying it I get this error:

> cMyModule\cMyResource : Class 'cMyResource' requires
>   that a value of type 'String' be provided for property 
>   'OptionalKey2'. At :167 char:9
>   +         cMyResource Res1
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingValueForMandatoryProperty,cMyModule\cMyResource

Comment: I've [asked on meta for the creation of the `mof` and `cim` tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278450/can-someone-create-tags-for-mof-managed-object-format-and-cim-common-informat) for this question if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, and in my experience, the answer is no.

Having a `[key]` property implies that it is required.

In addition, having a DSC resource with no `[key]` properties doesn't work correctly. I tried to create one a while back and nothing complained until implementation at which point the LCM threw errors about there being no key properties.

Comment: In case it really is not possible, would you suggest some kind of workaround to maintain that behavior? Thanks for the tip about no key properties also.

Comment: A possible workaround is to just not use `[key]` for that property. What is it about `[key]` that you want attached to the property when present?

Comment: By just not using `[Key]` I'd not allow one to specify two resources which diverge only on that property, but I want that. Notice that in my question, the second valid configuration contains Res2 and Res3, and they differ only by this optional key. If I remove the key, they wouldn't be able to be specified together in the same configuration.

Comment: Ah got it, I see what you're going for now. I'm not sure if this will work, but maybe keep the parameter optional in DSC, but give it a dummy default value. In MOF, make it `[key]`. Ideally, the default value satisfies the `[key]` and on the DSC side, nothing needs to be specified.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. If the property is marked as `[Key]` on the shema.mof but I don't specify it in the configuration, it fails as soon as I try to create the computer mof files, before I even run `Start-DSCConfiguraiton`. I'm not sure what to do now, I really needed that functionality.

Comment: Is specifying a dummy value in your configuration not an option? I know it's not ideal. There's an extreme option whereby you run a script that preprocesses the configs and looks for the missing mandatory parameter and fills in the dummy value, but that's probably not useful.

Comment: Yeah I thought about going that way... it's indeed not ideal but should work fine. For the moment I left it out completely just to make what I wanted work. I'll try to update it to that dummy value idea later on and report back.

Comment: If you find an answer do post it; I'm interested.

Comment: You can even post a default value in the MOF file like this: `[Key] String ConfigurationPath = "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST";`, but you continues to get the error _Class 'xIisMimeTypeMapping' requires that a value of type 'String' be provided for property 'ConfigurationPath'_

Comment: Looking for a good answer here too, I've resorted to using a 'Fake Identifier' in my DSC resource schema when I run into this problem.  It's a workaround, good enough for now but wish there was a better solution.